# Rendering attachment controls inside tab/page Azure DevOps Work item form

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I want to display Attachment controls inside a Tab/Page of a Work item form.
Is it possible using Azure DevOps extension?

like as shown in image below.
[image]

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT, thank you for the response, It did worked for on premises environment , but I am facing download issue with this extension. When I click on download option a new tab gets opened without download. Tried in Chrome, edge browsers. Any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> display Attachment controls inside a Tab/Page of a Work item form

You can try to use [Attachments Group](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.attachments-group) extension.

[image]

After installation, you can adjust the display position of the Attachments group in the custom process.

[image]